# How to assign series of integers to pointer var in struct

Tags: c, pointers, variables, struct

Using c language, If I have I declared four random integers how do I go about storing them inside the series variable and then accessing them?

```
int  a =3;
int b=4;
int c=5; 
int d=6;

typedef struct struct1
{
int *series;
int num1;
double num2;
double num3; 
}
Struct1;
```

I declared the struct as

```
Struct1 mystruct;
```

Comment: Assuming one could do this, how would you expect to get them back *out* afterwards?  And why can't each of your 4 values be its own field in `struct1`?

Comment: I am new to learning c, so Im not sure. Plus they must be in the series. @ScottHunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you allocate the memory you need to store them using `malloc`. You'll need to include `<stdlib.h>` to access that function. You need enough space for 4 `int` so:

```
mystruct.series = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```

Then you just store and access the data like you'd do for any other array:

```
mystruct.series[0] = a;
mystruct.series[1] = b;
mystruct.series[2] = c;
mystruct.series[3] = d;
```

Once you don't need it anymore, remember to free the memory to avoid a memory leak with `free(mystruct.series)`.